# WinSCP in Wine - Black Box, no handling possible

Tags: gnome3, nvidia, wine, antergos

```
OS: Antergos linux-lts 4.4.15-1
Wine: wine-1.9.13 (Staging)
Desktop: gnome-desktop 1:3.20.2-1
Graphic: GeForce GTX 770
Kernel driver in use: nvidia (nvidia 367.27-1)
```

If i start `winscp` (Installed via AUR), i can't use it - on the right side i have a black box, and the complete window is not clickable / usable:

[image: Screenshot of behaviour]

If i start `winscp` with the [option to render a virtual desktop](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_get_Wine_to_launch_an_application_in_a_virtual_desktop.3F) there are no such black boxes and i can use winscp normal.

Is there a solution to fix the black box in the normal / non windowed mode?

Answer (score 0):

Using a windows program on a linux machine for ssh is a bit unusual, but that's just me.

If you are looking for a gui-frontend for ssh you are maybe better off with the answers provided here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/616863/gui-ssh-for-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I really like winscp.. It runs on several other desktop pcs on the same OS (also same version) without any problems. Thanks anyway